# list as a dictionary value

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

as the dictonary value I am having strings, how can I make it a list. 
my code:

```
user_input = 'key1 : value1, key2 : value2, key3 : value1'
myDict = {}
user_input = user_input.split(',')
v = []
for i in user_input:
    i = i.strip()
    elem = i.split(':')
    key = elem[1].strip()
    value = elem[0].strip()

    if key in myDict:
        myDict[key] += value
    else:
        myDict[key] = value

print(myDict)
```

My output:

```
{'value1': 'key1key3', 'value2': 'key2'}
```

the outputs I want:

```
{"value1" : ["key1", "key3"], "value2" : ["key2"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple fix! Just had to declare `value` as a list.

```
user_input = 'key1 : value1, key2 : value2, key3 : value1'
myDict = {}
user_input = user_input.split(',')
v = []
for i in user_input:
    i = i.strip()
    elem = i.split(':')
    key = elem[1].strip()
    value = [elem[0].strip()]

    if key in myDict:
        myDict[key] += value
    else:
        myDict[key] = value

print(myDict)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
user_input = 'key1 : value1, key2 : value2, key3 : value1'

k = [x.split(':')[0].strip() for x in user_input.split(',')]
v = [x.split(':')[1].strip() for x in user_input.split(',')]
d = dict(zip(k, v))

def keysgen(v):
    return sorted(k for k in d.keys() if d[k] == v)
    
print({v: keysgen(v) for v in sorted(set(d.values()))})
```

Output:

```
{'value1': ['key1', 'key3'], 'value2': ['key2']}
```